# Continuous integration with python 2.7 / flask / mongoDB / git

Tags: python, git, continuous-integration, flask, gunicorn

How should I implement continuous integration on my new application? Currently, this is how we're pushing to production - please bear with me, I know this is far from sane:

1. From local, git push origin production (the production codebase is kept on the production branch, modifications are either written directly there and committed, or files are checked out individually from another branch. Origin is the remote production server)
2. On the remote box, sudo stop gunicorn (application is running as a process)
3. cp ~/flaskgit/application.py ~/flask/applicaion.py (the git push origin from local pushes to an init -bare repo with a post-update hook that populates the files in ~/flaskgit. ~/flask is where the gunicorn service runs the application under a virtualenv)
4. sudo start gunicorn

we do our testing with the ~/flaskgit code running on a different port. once it looks good we do the CP

I would love to have something more fluid. I have used jenkins in the past, and loved the experience - but didn't set it up.

What resources / utilities should I look up in order to do this well?

Thank you!

Comment: You could have a look at the [configuration files of the jenkins setup](https://github.com/plone/jenkins.plone.org) that's running on [http://jenkins.plone.org](http://jenkins.plone.org). Plone is a CMS written in Python / built on top of Zope, we use git (GitHub) for version control, and [buildout](http://www.buildout.org/) for deployment / setting up reproducible testing configurations.

Comment: You don't have to stop and start Gunicorn. Just owerwrite the application.py with new one and send HUP signal to gunicorn master process. It should reload your application with new code.

Answer (score 1):

buildbot, jenkins/hudson but these give you continuous integration in the sense you can run a "make" equivalent with every code base change through a commit hook. You could also look at vagrant if there is something there for you for creating repeatable vm's wrt to config/setup. Could tie it with a commit hook.